# Flow of execution is not going as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jakarta-mail

I ran into a weired problem. My program is not executing as per the expectations.

```java
public void sendPasswordResetCode(String email, Long code){ 
    log.info("inside");
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = configureMailProps();
    log.info("mail props {}",javaMailSender.toString());
    SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
    msg.setTo(email);
    msg.setSubject("Password reset code.");
    msg.setText("use this code to reset your password "+code);
    javaMailSender.send(msg);        
}
```

the next methods:

```java
private JavaMailSenderImpl configureMailProps() {
    log.info("inside config");
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    GmailConfigurations config = new GmailConfigurations();
    GmailSettings gmail = config.getGmailSettings();
    log.info(gmail.toString());
    try {
        mailSender.setHost(gmail.getHost());
        mailSender.setPort(gmail.getPort());

        mailSender.setUsername(gmail.getGmail());

        mailSender.setPassword(gmail.getAppPassword());            
    }
    catch(RuntimeException ex) {
        log.info("exce here");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.info("Before seing props");
    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    log.info("Mail {}",mailSender.toString());
    return mailSender;        
} 
    
@Slf4j
@Component
public class GmailConfigurations {

    @Autowired
    private EmailCredService emailCred;
        
    public GmailSettings getGmailSettings() {
        log.info("inside gmail seings");
        GmailSettings gmail = new GmailSettings();
        EmailCredSetting cred = emailCred.getEmailCred();
        if(cred != null) {
            gmail.setAppPassword(cred.getPassword());
            gmail.setGmail(cred.getEmail());            
        }
        gmail.setPort(587);
        gmail.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        log.info("Inside gmail seings 2{}", gmail.toString());
        return gmail;
    }    
}
```

The output is:

1. inside
2. inside config
3. inside gmail seings

After that nothing is getting printed and email is not send. nothing is happening.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try to debug your application by stepping through from a breakpoint?

Comment: Thank you. So finally found the cause. there was null pointer exception coming byt strange app was not throwing or printing that to console.